# JSF represent tree data as nested squares

Tags: jsf-2, tree

I need to represent a tree data in JSF. But it should not look like a tree, but rather use nested squares. All my efforts did utterly fail. I tried to build a recursive composite component, but failed due to view/build time issues.

I don't think I can reuse a tree component, since they don't provide the required visual outcome.

I need some direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed not possible with a composite. You need to use a fullworthy component like as almost all those component/utility libraries have in their assortiment. Given that you want full control over the tree markup, you thus need a markupless tree component. [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) has a [`<o:tree>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/tree) component which doesn't generate any markup. As an example, if you intend to generate a `<div>` for every tree node, regardless of the depth level, then do so:

```
<o:tree value="#{bean.tree}" var="item">
    <o:treeNode>
        <o:treeNodeItem>
            <div>
                #{item}
                <o:treeInsertChildren />
            </div>
        </o:treeNodeItem>
    </o:treeNode>
</o:tree>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try this. Unfortunately the showcase you have linked is down.

Comment: Thanks again @BalusC. You helped me a lot! I proposed a minor edit, where the `o:treeInsertChildren` is inside the div, so it is exactly what I asked for.

Comment: Oh, I now understand that you meant "nested" when you said "self containing". Okay, then that's indeed the way to go.